# Cannot assign a value of type 'NSData!' to a value of type 'AnyObject?'

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I just started to learn Swift by following tutorials and online courses.

I can't save in Parse the Facebook user profile picture due to this error:

> Cannot assign a value of type 'NSData!' to a value of type 'AnyObject?'

My code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   var user = PFUser.currentUser()

   var accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString

   let url = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1&access_token="+accessToken)

   let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
   NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(),
       completionHandler: {
       response, data, error in

       let image = UIImage(data: data)
       self.profilePic.image = image

     user["image"] = data -> Cannot assign a value of type 'NSData!' to a value of type 'AnyObject?'
     user.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instantiate a PFFile with your image data:

```
var imageFile = PFFile.fileWithData(data)
```

Save it in background, and then set user["image"] = imageFile on save callback